# Maintaining scroll position causes memory leak. Why?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I created a web tool and one of my pages contains two (vertically) scroll-able tables that get their data from a MySQL database.

Since I have a lot of users doing many operations on the database, I wanted to make just the top table refresh itself constantly and the amount of data is huge. I achieved this using AJAX:

```
$('#live_refresh_station_available').load('live_refresh/devices_live/load_available.php');
```

I have a separate file that contains the top table and I load it every 2000 milliseconds using setInterval().

Surprisingly this works just fine in terms of memory consumption, at about a stable ~100MB. But then I wanted to add a way to maintain the scroll position in the top table since otherwise it is reset every 2000 milliseconds so not very user friendly. I found that the most effective way would be with cookies so here is how I did it:

```
<script>
    function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*10000));
        var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
    }
</script>

<script>
    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
        }
        return "";
    }
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function (event){
        var scroll = getCookie("scroll_1");
        if (scroll != "") { // If scroll value exists, keep it
            $("tbody.scrollContent").scrollTop(scroll);
        } 

        $("tbody.scrollContent").scroll(function(){
            var scroll = $("tbody.scrollContent").scrollTop();
            setCookie("scroll_1", $("tbody.scrollContent").scrollTop(), 1);
        });
    });
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function (event){
        var scroll = getCookie("scroll_2");
        if (scroll != "") { // If scroll value exists, keep it
            $("tbody.scrollContent2").scrollTop(scroll);
        } 

        $("tbody.scrollContent2").scroll(function(){
            var scroll = $("tbody.scrollContent2").scrollTop();
            setCookie("scroll_2", $("tbody.scrollContent2").scrollTop(), 1);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Cookies expire after 10000 milliseconds. I added the scripts to that file that I load with AJAX and they maintain the scroll position just fine.

The problem now is that the memory used by the browser (I tried on Chrome and Firefox) keeps piling up until eventually the tab crashes. Even if I switch to some other page (so no more loading), that particular tab will not deallocate the memory - this makes me think there is some kind on memory leak.

As I mentioned before, this happens only if I try to keep the scroll position using cookies, so the .load itself is not the problem here. Any ideas on how to fix this?

**Edit**: I made a Heap Snapshot using the Chrome Dev Tools and I found a lot of detached nodes that are HTMLTableSectionElement type, but I don't see any connection with the cookie scripts.